# unresolved external symbol in C++ managed

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c++-cli, managed

I have C++ managed dll compiled with /clr that has some global functions.

for example

```
void Managed2UnManaged(DataStructures::AAA^ elem, DataStructures::CPP::AAA* copy_elem);
```

when I try to use these functions in a C++ managed console application I get the following errors

error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00048C) "void __clrcall Managed2UnManaged(class DataStructures::AAA ^,class DataStructures::CPP::AAA *)" (?Managed2UnManaged@@$$FYMXP$AAVAAA@DataStructures@NextIn@@PAV1CPP@23@@Z)

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __clrcall Managed2UnManaged(class DataStructures::AAA ^,class DataStructures::CPP::AAA *)" (?Managed2UnManaged@@$$FYMXP$AAVAAA@DataStructures@NextIn@@PAV1CPP@23@@Z)

I added to the console application a reference to the dll but it still gives the error.

I also tried adding  __declspec(dllexport) but then I get

error C3395: 'Managed2UnManaged' : __declspec(dllexport) cannot be applied to a function with the __clrcall calling convention

and if I specify __stdcall I get

error C4439: 'Managed2UnManaged' : function definition with a managed type in the signature must have a __clrcall calling convention

I am using VS2012.

the h file has

```
class XXX {
 public:
static void Managed2UnManaged(DataStructures::RegResult^ elem,     DataStructures::CPP::RegResult* copy_elem);
};
```

and the cpp file

```
 void XXX::Managed2UnManaged(DataStructures::RegResult^ elem, DataStructures::CPP::RegResult* copy_elem)
{

}
```

Problem Solved. the problem was that I also needed to declare the class public ref. this caused a different problem because that the native c++ types are private. so I had to use the make_public pragma.
Thanks all.

Comment: did this function exported by the DLL? if it is, please check the calling conventions are the same, the error message indicates the calling convention is clrcall.

Comment: I tried exporting by adding __declspec(dllexport) but then I get error C3395: 'Managed2UnManaged' : __declspec(dllexport) cannot be applied to a function with the __clrcall calling convention

Comment: _clrcall is not compatible with dllexport. Is your console application  a native application, you may change it to a managed one.

Comment: no the console is managed as well and compiled with /clr

Comment: Just checked some documents, in this case, you should use a static member function instead.

Comment: You only posted the declaration of the function.  Where is the code for the function actually located?

Comment: @Hans the actual definition of the function is in a cpp file.

Comment: @Simon I tried putting the functions into a class as static functions but same result unresolved token (0A000492)

Comment: if I declare the class as ref class I get the following error error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000001) XXX::Managed2UnManaged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem may be that the CLR doesn't allow global functions.

You must create a managed class and write your function as a static member function of that class, for that function to be exported.

Comment: No, global functions are supported.  The compiler simply makes the methods of a class named `<Module>`

Comment: @Hans I changed the code but still have the same problem. I edited the original post to show the code in h and cpp files